# GCP forward proxy solution for whitelisting domain names on outbound traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I use squid in my vpc as a forward proxy and to sanitize my outgoing traffic to only allow certain domains. Is there a cloud native solution in GCP that accomplishes the same thing? I just want to be able to whitelist certain domain names being requested from some of my instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cloud-native solution is [DiscrimiNAT](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/chasersystems-public/discriminat) though. It allows plugging in domain allowlists straight into GCP Firewall Rules, **without** the need to configure apps to use an explicit proxy or deal with certificates. The association of Firewall Rules with workloads by use of Network Tags (as is the GCP-way) then dictates which egress FQDN rules apply to which VM Instances, GKE Clusters, Cloud Functions, etc. even in a Shared VPC setting.

Also has a handy traffic discovery, monitoring mode to allow building the allowlists with use of data from GCP Logging and a couple of `gcloud` commands pasted into Cloud Shell: https://youtu.be/Q0ntWv4bA1U (3½ min video.)

It isn't a forward-proxy technically, but an [NGFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next-generation_firewall) accomplishing the specific requirement of filtering outbound traffic by [FQDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).

Disclosure: It's a marketplace product and I've written protocol parsers for them in Rust!

Comment: This is concerning in the same fashion as Secure Web Proxy in that it's basically a single instance doing the work for you, so you then need to handle scaling and there is no mention of ability to place this behind an internal LB, so in high volume environments this looks like it might be a weak link

Comment: It very much deploys behind an Internal LB when deployed through their Terraform module: https://chasersystems.com/docs/discriminat/gcp/diy/#terraform-modules.

Comment: interesting. Do you then have to pay per number of instances?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native solution in that use case in GCP as of the moment, but you can check [this documentation](https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/ise_hardening_guide_gcp.pdf) to help you harden your GCP infrastructure.

You can also file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) to give them an idea with your use case and possibly consider adding it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There's now GCP's own Secure Web Proxy product which should work albeit with some (severe) limitations:
https://cloud.google.com/secure-web-proxy/docs/overview

Personally haven't tried it yet, it seems like I am going separate GKE cluster and autoscaling squid pods.